# Wireguard with VPS for mobile clients for all traffic routing

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I have been trying to configure Wireguard as a VPN for accessing my home network which partially I have been successful. But I still am experiencing problems when trying to make two things happen.

1. I want to route all traffic through the VPN
2. Once the client is connected to the VPN it should use my home external IP address as the Public IP and not the one from my mobile carrier.

For context at home, I use Homeassistant with the Wireguard addon installed. The configuration YAML is as follows:

```
server:
  host: wireguard
  addresses:
    - 172.27.66.1
  dns:
    - 192.168.0.126
peers:
  - name: vps
    public_key: redacted
    endpoint: PublicIP:port (redacted)
    addresses:
      - 10.9.0.0/24
    allowed_ips: []
    client_allowed_ips: []
    persistentKeepalive: 25
  - name: laptop
    addresses:
      - 172.27.66.3
    allowed_ips: []
    client_allowed_ips: []
log_level: debug
```

My VPS that is hosted offsite has the wg0.conf as follows:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.9.0.3/24
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
ListenPort = port redacted
PrivateKey = redacted

[Peer]
PublicKey = redacted
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.0.126/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer]
PublicKey = redacted
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.0/24, 10.9.0.5/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer]
PublicKey = redacted
AllowedIPs = 10.9.0.4/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

The first Peer is the one that connects to the home network's Wireguard. All of this currently works and I am able to access the server 192.168.0.126 which is the home assistant and from testing ad blocking also seems to be working on the mobile clients.

My issue is that I don't seem to be able to access other devices on the network even though AllowedIPs is set to 192.168.0.0/24.

And from what I have read to route all traffic through the VPN I would need to add the 0.0.0.0/0, or::/0 for IPv6. But when I add that to the AllowedIPs and restart the wg0 interface I immediately lose connection to the VPS and have to reset and stop the service from starting as the VPS becomes no longer reachable. I assume the issue is that I may need some specific routing rules but I am unsure what needs to be properly set up. The ip tables have no rules and are set to accept all traffic.

VPS ip route:

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.4 metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.4
10.9.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.0.3
168.63.129.16 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.4 metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.4 metric 100
192.168.0.0/24 dev wg0 scope link
192.168.0.126 dev wg0 scope link
```

Home wireguard ip route:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev end0  metric 100
10.9.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.126 dev end0
172.30.32.0/23 dev hassio scope link  src 172.30.32.1
172.30.232.0/23 dev docker0 scope link  src 172.30.232.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev end0 scope link  src 192.168.0.126  metric 100
```

I would appreciate any help in troubleshooting this to get all of the traffic going through the VPN and using my home's Public IP address instead if possible.

Comment: You haven't been clear on what's the client OS or shared the client config. At least with wg-quick on Linux, `0.0.0.0/0` in `AllowedIPs=` does not actually cause *all* traffics to be routed into the tunnel, but traffics not covered by the existing non-default routes. If there is subnet conflict, you'll need to customize the policy routing. Either way, we are talking about client config here, not the server one.

Comment: Also, to use the wireguard server as the clients Internet gateway, you'll need to source NAT the traffics from the clients. (If you want to server's router to do the job instead, you'll need a route on it for the VPN subnet, with the server's LAN IP as the gateway address.)

Comment: The home assistant wireguard runs on hassos Linux based operating system I believe in a docker container. The VPS runs on Ubuntu. The actual clients that will be using the VPN are mobile iOS devices that run the wireguard app. I would appreciate any help on the routing should be done. As making changes just seems to break the connection.